# Instagram: untagging photo removal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json, instagram

We're using the Instagram API to fetch a list of photos tagged with a certain hashtag and displayed in real-time. Building this using Rails.

Our problem: How do I construct a query that removes the photos from my displayed fetch when the user untags the photos without refreshing the browser?

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` remove the image tag or set its display to none